# How do I edit individual meta tags on a panelized page?

Tags: 7, panels, meta-tags, distributions

Setup I have: Drupal 7, Panopoly 7.x-1.30, Metatag 7.x-1.13

I've installed and enabled both the metatag and metatag_panels modules. Perhaps I'm just not looking in the right place, but I don't see any way to add custom metatags (title and description) to an individual panelized landing page.

On an individual node page (which isn't panelized), I can click the "edit" tab, and at the bottom is a form that lets me customize the metatags for just that node. But if I click the "edit" tab on my landing page, there is no such form. Clicking the "customize this page" button which invokes the panelizer doesn't seem to offer any way to edit the metatags, either.

I've read the documentation and searched the drupal.org forums, but nothing has made a solution clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it has nothing to do with the panels; the Metatag plugin just doesn't support landing pages. Converting the needed landing pages to customized content pages solved my problem.